# How to create an App which syncs two devices basing on a remote db value

Tags: android, synchronization, publish-subscribe

I'd like to make an app (and a webserver) where I have this scenario :

1. device1 makes a post and set a value in a remote db.
2. device2 is alerted of the changed value in the db and gets the value.

What I need is obiously the pattern, an implementation of it or just the architecture I could use to develop the solution a presented.

I was thinking about a pub/sub pattern. What do you suggest?

EDIT : 
My idea was a shared grocery list (like Bring to be clear). I would like that, when someone puts an item into the shared list, the list will be updated in "realtime" on the other client.

I found rethinkdb https://www.rethinkdb.com/
and could be useful (just like firebase) but I don't know if it's possible to invoke it in the app directly. I don't know how to integrate the android app and the db.

Answer (score 2):

Without something more specific, I suggest either https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/ or https://firebase.google.com/

Please, provide more specific questions if you want more specific answers.

**Update**

While I have no experience with rethinkdb, it has a Java API that probably is compatible with Android (because of Gradle integration instructions). See [Java driver page](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/install-drivers/java/) for more information.

Take into account that unless there is some provider that offers the server component as a service, you will have to manage your own server and install the server component by following [this instructions](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/install/). Notice that there is an official Docker image available which can be useful in some scenarios.

Comment: +1 for Firebase. Almost all their tutorials/live coding showcases show exactly the same functionality as you describe in your question. Shared database user A pushes a value to and the value updates on user Bs phone in (almost) real time

Comment: My idea was a shared grocery list (like Bring to be clear). I would like that, when someone puts an item into the shared list, the list will be updated in "realtime" on the other client.

I found rethinkdb https://www.rethinkdb.com/ and could be useful (just like firebase) but I don't know if it's possible to invoke it in the app directly. I don't know how to integrate the android app and the db.